# error multi user php

Tags: php, mysqli

this is the code that have 3 user, the code just running for 2 user,it's in condition idLogin=1 and idLogin=2, i don't know why in condition idLogin=3 it does't work .

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ (E_NOTICE | E_WARNING));
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$login = $_POST['login'];

if (isset($login)) {
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "loginda");
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM login where username='$username' and        password='$password'");
    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();
    $idLogin = $row['id_login'];
    $user = $row['username'];
    $pass = $row['password'];
    $type = $row['type_login'];

    if ($user == $username && $pass = $password) {
        session_start();
        if ($idLogin == "1") {
            $_SESSION['mysesi'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['myid'] = $idLogin;
            echo "<script>window.location.assign('admin.php')</script>";
        } elseif ($idLogin == "2") {
            $_SESSION['mysesi'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['myid'] = $idLogin;
            echo "<script>window.location.assign('index.php')</script>";
        } elseif ($idLogin == "3") {
            $_SESSION['mysesi'] = $user;
            $_SESSION['myid'] = $idLogin;
            echo "<script>window.location.assign('index2.php')</script>";
        } else {
        ?>
```

this is code for index2.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['mysesi']) && !isset($_SESSION['myid'])=='3')
{
 echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php')</script>";
 }
 ?>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 ..........
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I don't think that you can check bool **isset** for **$S_SESSION['myid']**, while checking its contents within the same if statement. I think you might have to check that the sessions are set first, then check the value of **$_SESSION['myid']**.

Try this:

```
if ((!isset($_SESSION['mysesi']) && !isset($_SESSION['myid'])) || $_SESSION['myid'] !='3')
{ 
   echo "<script>window.location.assign('login.php')</script>";
}
```

You should also consider using [PDO objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for MySQL interactions. And even more importantly, you need to sanitize your user inputs below using them in your MySQL Query, if you are going to use mysqli the way you that currently do.

Lastly, you should not be storing your passwords in plain text. There are a number of hashing algorithms available to hash passwords before storing them in your database. However PHP5.5 and up includes the [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to make things easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think error may be here...

```
if($user==$username && $pass=$password) // here is single `=` sign
```

It should be like as:

```
 if($user==$username && $pass==$password)  // double `==` for comparasion
```

Comment: if this would have been the error would it work for the first two login id